# c++ loops happy number cs101.1x

Tags: c++

Practice Programming Assignment (PPA 03)

Happy Numbers: A number is called a happy number, if you repeat the process, of squaring the sum of the digits, till the value 1 is obtained. E.g. You need to do the following to perform this check: (a) compute the sum of the squares of its digits (b) if the resultant value is 1, then the number is a happy number, else execute point (a). If a number is not a happy number, there will be an endless loop/cycle to this execution. 
Task: In this programming assignment, you are required to write code that checks whether the number is a happy number or not, for 10 cycles (iterations) only. 2 examples of happy numbers (limited to 10 cycles ) are given below:

You are required to do the following:
Find the sum of square of the digits of the number.
Check the result obtained in point 1. If it is 1, assign value 1 to the variable 'finalNumber', else again execute point 1, till the number obtained is 1 or till the number of cycle increases to 10.
Assign the iteration value to the variable 'cycle_no'.

Write the required code in C++. My code so far:

```
int number, finalnumber, a, cycle_no;
cin>>number;
for (cycle_no=0,finalnumber=0;cycle_no<=10;cycle_no+=1)
{
    for (a=0;number>0;number/=10) 
        a=number%10;
    finalnumber+=(a*a);
    if (finalnumber==1)
        break;
    else
        number=finalnumber;
    continue;
}
cout<<finalnumber;
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Are you just asking someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: pls see edited question and i mputting my code .a

Comment: int number , finalnumber , a , cycle_no ;
cin>>number;
for (cycle_no=0,finalnumber=0;cycle_no<=10;cycle_no+=1)
    {for (a=0;number>0;number/=10 )
       a=number%10;
       finalnumber+=(a*a);
    if (finalnumber==1)
    break;
    else 
    number=finalnumber;
    continue;}
    cout<<finalnumber;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using namespace std;
    int  a, number ;
    int cycle_no=1;
    int sumdigits( int number) 
    {
     int sum=0;  

     while(number>0)
     {a=number%10;
     number/=10;
     sum+=(a*a);} 
     return sum;
     }

     int main(){
      cin>>number;
      while(cycle_no<=10)
      {cycle_no+=1;
      if(sumdigits(number)==1)
      break;
      else
      number=sumdigits(number);


      }if( sumdigits(number)==1)
      cout<<sumdigits (number );
      else cout<<number;
       }
```